# resize image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code to resize an image but the  image  doesn't look so good:

```
public Bitmap ProportionallyResizeBitmap(Bitmap src, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{

    // original dimensions
    int w = src.Width;
    int h = src.Height;
    // Longest and shortest dimension
    int longestDimension = (w > h) ? w : h;
    int shortestDimension = (w < h) ? w : h;
    // propotionality
    float factor = ((float)longestDimension) / shortestDimension;
    // default width is greater than height
    double newWidth = maxWidth;
    double newHeight = maxWidth / factor;
    // if height greater than width recalculate
    if (w < h)
    {
        newWidth = maxHeight / factor;
        newHeight = maxHeight;
    }
    // Create new Bitmap at new dimensions
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)result))
        g.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You might take a look at the http://imageresizing.net library. [There is a long list of pitfalls to avoid with image resizing if you do it yourself](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `InterpolationMode` of the graphics object to some value such as `HighQualityBicubic`.  This should ensure that resize/scaled image looks much better than the "default".

So, in the code you have posted, instead of doing:

```
// Create new Bitmap at new dimensions
Bitmap result = new Bitmap((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)result))
   g.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
return result;
```

Try doing this instead:

```
// Create new Bitmap at new dimensions
Bitmap result = new Bitmap((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)result))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
}
return result;
```

(Note the line setting the `InterpolationMode` property to one of the InterpolationMode enumeration's values).

Please see this link:
[How to: Use Interpolation Mode to Control Image Quality During Scaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e.aspx)
For further information on controlling the quality of an image when resizing/scaling.

Also see this CodeProject article:
[Resizing a Photographic image with GDI+ for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx)
For information of the different visual effects the various InterpolationMode enumeration settings will have on an image.  (About two-thirds of the way down the article, under the section entitled, "One last thing...").

Answer (score 0):

If you need an on-the-fly resize I suggest you to try an HttpHandler I write recently, [I've posted the code on my blog](http://www.recoding.it/?p=270) (sorry, but is in italian).

With some modifies you can use the code also for save the transformed image on the disk.